# ffmpeg encoder streaming issues

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg encoder on linux. I started with a custom built server Dual 1366 2.6 Ghz Xeon CPUs (6 cores) with 16 GB RAM with Ubuntu 16.04 minimal install. Built ffmpeg with h264 and aac. I am taking live source OTA channels and encoding/streaming them with following parameters

-vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -crf 25 -x264opts keyint=60:min-keyint=60:scenecut=-1 -bufsize 7000k -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6300k -muxrate 6000k -s 1920x1080 -format yuv420p -g 60 -sn -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 44100

And I am able to successfully udp out using mpegts. My problem starts with 5th stream. The server can handle four streams and as soon as I introduce 5th stream I start seeing hiccups in output. Looking at my cpu usage using top I still see only 65% to 75% usage with occasional 80% hit. Memory usage is well within acceptable parameters. So I am wondering either top is not giving me accurate cpu usage or something is not right with ffmpeg. The server is isolated for udp in/out on a 1 Gbps network.

I decided to up the cpu power and installed two 3.5 Ghz CPUs (6 cores) thinking it was perhaps the cpu clock. To my surprise the results were no different. So now I am wondering is there some built in limit I am hitting when I process at 1080p. If I change the resolution to 720p it is able to process 8 streams but 720 is not acceptable. 
My target is 10 1080p streams per server.
So my questions are
1. If I use a quad motherboard and up the cpu count to 4 (6 or 8 cores) will I get 10 1080p streams? Is there any theoretical max I can go with ffmpeg per machine?
2. Do cores matter more or does clock matter more?
3. Any suggestions in improvement with my options. I have tried ultrafast preset but the output quality is unacceptable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you really excluded the CPU? Make sure to check how each individual core is operating. If no core is reaching 100%, then your most likely candidate is bandwidth: either your motherboard cannot handle all the data going back and forth, or your memory. Exchanging memory with a faster version is a simple test and should give you your answer.